# Driving distance between 2 locations

Tags: php, google-maps

There are plenty of pages about this but I've yet to find something useful that actually works. Currently, I have used the Google Distance Matrix and found the distance between two locations, however had no luck transferring the distance from JavaScript to PHP. I made a post on here yesterday about that with no success. So the other option I have is to find the distance using the matrix in PHP. I'll still show the map and everything, just on the next page I'd like to get the distance value between the two locations to use it to find a cost for a trip that is then sent to mysql database, so I need to get that value to PHP.

I've tried various examples I've found online but none seem to work for me.

```
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:London%20to:Dover';
$data = @file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($data);
print $obj->meters;
```

For example that. I have no idea how to do what I'm trying to, regardless of searching for days on end and would really appreciate some help as I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: removing the error suppressing @ would be a start

Comment: `{"name":"from:London to:Dover","Status":{"code":604,"request":"directions"}}` is what that URL returns for me...not sure how you are going to calculate a distance from that.

Comment: possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254641/mysql-query-select-nearest-places-by-a-given-coordinates/14255279#14255279

Comment: well i have no idea, i've just been trying different examples online.

Comment: @crush: Strange, I get `"code":200` and a JSON formatted string containing `"Distance":{"meters":4217…`.

Comment: I get a valid JSON response with coordinates. *shrugs* Gonan need more

Comment: i need to find the driving distance between two points :/

Comment: The JSON object actually contains all relevant information, including distance among other things

Comment: @Lubblobba - do you have the latitude and longitude of the two points

Comment: well i can put them in sure

Comment: i still get a blank page

Comment: @Lubblobba Have you checked if `file_get_contents()` actually succeeds? If it fails, it will simply return `false` and no error would be displayed.

Comment: i placed var_dump after each line, and the first 2 contained the data, but var_dump($obj) returns NULL, so the json_decode doesnt appear to work?

Comment: @Lubblobba Just to make sure - `var_dump($data)` actually displays the raw JSON?

Comment: Why am I getting the code 604....wtf

Comment: i have no idea, it contains a lot of stuff, this is a bit of it: string(5876) "{"name":"from:51.519894,-0.105667 to:51.129079,1.306925","Status":{"code":200,"request":"directions"}"Placemark":[{"id":"","address":"Farringdon Rd\/A201","AddressDetails":{"Thoroughfare":{"ThoroughfareName":"Farringdon Rd\/A201"}
and it continues

Comment: The actual problem is in `json_decode`: [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/json_last_error) returns `JSON_ERROR_UTF8`...

Comment: @Lubblobba This means the request is successful and you actually get data back. It also means `json_decode()` fails. You can check for the possible failure with `echo json_last_error();`

Comment: @Lubblobba harpax's updated answer would prevent the error in the JSON decoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be almost ok with that, except that the json is in a different format. The last line of your example should be:

```
echo $obj->Directions->Distance->meters;
```

for more infos on the format of the answer try a var_dump in php .. Hope that helps

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:London%20to:Dover';
    $data = @file_get_contents($url);
    $data = utf8_decode($data);
    $obj = json_decode($data);
    echo $obj->Directions->Distance->meters;
?>
```

Comment: i placed var_dump after each line, and the first 2 contained the data, but var_dump($obj) returns NULL

Comment: seems like you have an encoding problem then .. I updated my post

Comment: Your code works, but I think it's strange you get such a malformed JSON string from Google Maps.

Comment: brilliant, thank you so much. and thanks to everyone who replied!

Comment: @MarcelKorpel that is a bit surprising. Especially that a utf8_**de**code would do it

Comment: I think I found the issue: there's a UTF-8 encoded copyright symbol `©` in `$obj->Directions->copyrightsHtml` which gets converted to an ISO 8859-1 `?` by `utf8_decode`.