# Passbook with geofence

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, passbook, geofencing

Is it possible to preprogram passbook passes into my application and then they activate when the user enteres a specific geofence? So like when they enter the geofence a notification will come up on their phone and when they tap on it, it takes them to passbook where it adds the pass.
Language- Swift
Xcode 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes it is possible.

Use [CoreLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/) to trigger a local push notification on entry to the geofence, and then in response to the local push present the pass using the [PKAddPassesViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKAddPassesViewController_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/PKAddPassesViewController).  To cope with more than 20 locations, you can have your app poll your server on significant location changes and download the 20 closest locations.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Parse as my backend server. How would I ask it to download another 20 locations based on a significant location change? Could you write some sample code? (I'm a bit new to having my all connected to a server)

Comment: There are plenty of examples of how to retrieve the nearest locations from a given set of lat/long coordinates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254641/mysql-query-select-nearest-places-by-a-given-coordinates, as well as code for responding to significant location changes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8.  You will need to use a combination of the above and incorporate the output into a new pass bundle which you then will need to push to the device.