# How to receive a list of addresses in a certain radius android studio?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I am building an application that holds a lot of addresses in a server.  I want to get a list of addresses in a certain radius of the user and then compare them to the addresses held in the server.  The problem is I don't know how to set up a radius around the user, and I don't know how to get all the addresses in that radius.  I can get the user's address/location, and I know how to compare the addresses to the addresses in the server.  **Does anyone know how I might set up a radius around the user and get all the addresses in that radius?**  It doesn't have to be an answer in code, any ideas would be helpful, but a good explanation and some code would be useful.  Thank you!

Comment: You have two choices, do it on the client-side or do it on the server-side.  I think it makes more sense to do it server-side, as if you do it client-side you would need to download all addresses every time, and then filter them.   Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254641/mysql-query-select-nearest-places-by-a-given-coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)** to get the distance to each of the address and filter them by their distance to match the specified radius.